# gentoo: virtualbox-guest-additions donot load

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, kernel-modules, gentoo

I've installed gentoo as guest OS in virtualbox, and today I got with a problem.

The vbox guest additions didn't work and I failed to load the module manually.

Here is my console output:

```
$ vboxadd.sh: failed: modprobe vboxguest failed
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxguest': Exec format error

$ modinfo vboxguest
filename:   /lib/module/4.12.5-gentoo/misc/vboxguest.ko
version:    5.1.26 r117224
license:    GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
author:     Oracle Corporation
srcversion: C1622A97042B7117C430962
alias:      pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc*sc*i*
depends:
vermagic    4.12.5-gentoo SMP mod_unload modversions

$ uname -r
4.12.5-gentoo
$ modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxguest': Exec format error
```

Could anybody know what happened? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the Guest Additions entry on the Gentoo Wiki. [Guest Additions](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/VirtualBox#Guest_Additions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to load the image first in the OS. Go to to Devices -> Install Guest Additios (usually right ctrl+D). Copy the content to the drive. chmod +x VBoxLinuxGuestAdditios.sh(might have a typo), and the just run it as root.

You will need for this: gcc+ Compiler, The Kernel Headers(if the emerge -pv www-client/linux-headers-$(uname -r) don't cut it, install the virtual headers) and Perl.

Hope this solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

Try: `emerge --ask app-emulation/virtualbox-guest-additions`

Comment: Actually, I installed vbox-guest-addition in this method.